# Javascript matrix inversion

Tags: javascript, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am creating a javascript code for matrix inversion.But the function doesn't seem to run.
I want my inverted matrix to be displayed where the input matrix was.I have tried alerting values of the invertedMatrix instead of putting them into s but that didn't work either.Would be grateful for any help

html

```
<div id = "table3">
<div class = "header">Macierz odwrotna [2x2]</div>
 <form id = "row1">
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/><!--first row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/>
 </form>
 <form id = "row2">
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/><!--second row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/>
</form>
<div class = "count" onclick="invertedMatrix(2,'det2')"><a href = "#">Wylicz</a>    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function det(size, className){
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
var determinant = 0;
if(size == 2){
determinant = (arr[0].value*arr[3].value) - (arr[1].value*arr[2].value);
}
else if(size == 3){
determinant = (arr[0].value*((arr[4].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value * arr[7].value))) - 
(arr[1].value*((arr[3].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value * arr[6].value))) +
(arr[2].value*((arr[3].value*arr[7].value) - (arr[4].value * arr[6].value))); 
}
return determinant;
}

function invertedMatrix(size,className){
var invertedMatrix = new Array();
var additionalMatrix = new Array();
var matrix = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
if(size == 2){
    for(var i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            additionalMatrix[i].value = matrix[i].value;
        }
        else{
            additionalMatrix[i].value = -matrix[i].value;
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0;i < matrix.length;i++){
        invertedMatrix[i].value = (1/det(2,className)) *  additionalMatrix[i].value;
    }
}
for(var i = 0;i < matrix.length; i++){
document.getElementsByClassName(className).item(i).value = invertedMatrix[i].value;
}
}
```

EDIT!:if condition check should have i == 0 || i == 2 instead of what i've written.But still won't work anyway.

Comment: I think you really need to separate the code that reads the matrix from the DOM and writes it to the DOM from the code that calculates the determinant and the inverse.  This is too tangled.

Comment: <div class = "count" onclick="invertedMatrix('det2')"><a href = "#">Wylicz</a>    </div>
</div>

function invertedMatrix(className){
var invertedMatrix = new Array();
var additionalMatrix = new Array();
var matrix = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for(var i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
       additionalMatrix.push(matrix[i].value);
    }
    invertedMatrix=additionalMatrix.reverse();

for(var i = 0;i < matrix.length; i++){
document.getElementsByClassName(className).item(i).value = invertedMatrix[i];
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at my (work-in-progress) library [matrix.js](https://github.com/Airblader/matrixjs) that supports matrices of any dimension (if you don't need that, you can stop reading here as arbitrary sizes add extreme overhead).

The relevant code for inversion is

```
Matrix.prototype.inverse = function () {
    if( !this.isSquare() ) {
        throw new MatrixError( MatrixError.ErrorCodes.DIMENSION_MISMATCH, 'Matrix must be square' );
    }

    var M = this.augment( Matrix.eye( this.rows() ) ),
        row, row_before, new_row, i, j, k, factor, rows, columns;

    try {
        M = M.decomposeLU();
        rows = M.rows();
        columns = M.columns();

        for( i = rows; i > 1; i-- ) {
            row_before = M.__getRow( i - 1 );
            row = M.__getRow( i );
            factor = row_before[i - 1] / row[i - 1];

            new_row = [];
            for( k = 0; k < columns; k++ ) {
                new_row[k] = row_before[k] - row[k] * factor;
            }
            M.__setRow( i - 1, new_row );
        }

        for( j = 1; j <= rows; j++ ) {
            row = M.__getRow( j );
            new_row = [];

            for( k = 0; k < columns; k++ ) {
                new_row[k] = row[k] / row[j - 1];
            }

            M.__setRow( j, new_row );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        throw new MatrixError( MatrixError.ErrorCodes.MATRIX_IS_SINGULAR );
    }

    return M.submatrix( 1, rows, this.columns() + 1, columns );
};
```

However, you can see it has some dependencies to a LU decomposition, for example. If you're interested, take a look at it. The inverse is not exactly an optimal solution so far, but rather basic.

Comment: Note: this project was archived in 2019