# Javascript det calculation

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have got two functions that I use to calculate a determinant of a matrix recursively. The values are taken from the HTML form. But function doesn't run. Could somebody help me with this? I would be very grateful.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    element 0_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"/>
    element 0_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"/>
    element 1_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements"/>
    element 1_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements"/>
    <input type = "button" value = "clickMe" onclick = "determinant('elements','class')"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function create2Darray(clname){
    var A = document.getElementsByClassName(clname);
    var arr = new Array();
    var rows = Math.sqrt(A.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        arr[i] = new Array();
        for(var j = 0; j < rows;j++){
            arr[i][j] = A[i*rows + j].value;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function determinant (matrixClass,type) {
    if(type == 'class'){
        var matrix = create2Darray(matrixClass);
    } else if(type == 'name'){
        var matrix = new Array();
    }
    var det = 0;
    if (matrix.length == 1){
        return matrix[0][0];
    } else if (matrix.length == 2){
        return (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
    }

    var smaller = new Array();//creating an empty array for a matrix minor;
    for (var k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++){
        smaller[k] = [];
        for(var l = 0;l < matrix.length; l++){
            smaller[k][l] = [];
        }
    }       

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for (a = 1; a < matrix.length; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < matrix.length; b++) {
                if (b < i) {
                    smaller[a - 1][b] = matrix[a][b];
                } else if (b > i) {
                    smaller[a - 1][b - 1] = matrix[a][b];
                }
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            s = 1;
        } else {
            s = -1;
        }
        det += s * matrix[0][i] * (determinant(smaller,'name'));
    }
    return det;
    alert(det);
}
```

NOTE:A problem is with this recursion.I tried calculating and returning and alerting a determinant of a matrix 2x2 and it worked.But when I tried to do it with a 3x3 matrix it didn't.So please help

Comment: You should really look into the answers on other posts before constantly opening new questions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489816/javascript-matrix-inversion

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert` is after `return`.
Use `alert` function before `return` statement

```
alert(det);  
return det;
```

in you code function returns this case

```
else if(matrix.length == 2){
    return (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
}
```

You should place alert here

```
det = (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);  
alert (det);  
return det;
```

Comment: And what if I want to alert a det of a matrix bigger that 2x2?It won't work.But thanx anyway

Comment: well,that's the point of my function.It calculates recursively if a size of a matrix is bigger than 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you need to put the name attribute on the form tag:

```
<form name="det">
```

Then, give your input values names. For example:

```
element 0_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements" NAME="A"/>
element 0_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements" NAME="B"/>
element 1_0 <input type = "text" class = "elements" NAME="C"/>
element 1_1 <input type = "text" class = "elements" NAME="D"/>
<input NAME="E" type = "button" value = "clickMe" onclick = "determinant('elements','class')"/>
```

Finally, now that you have named everything, you can get the values in javascript with:

```
document.*formname*.*input name*.value
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Well,I want to make it universal so that I wouldn't have to change my javascript for another form.I want to use this algorithm a couple of times.But thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops are using undefined variables 'a' and 'b'

Answer (score 0):

When you creating "smaller" you didn't shrink matrix.

```
for (var k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++){
    smaller[k] = [];
    for(var l = 0;l < matrix.length; l++){
        smaller[k][l] = [];
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
for (var k = 0; k < matrix.length - 1; k++) {
    smaller[k] = [];

    for(var l = 0; l < matrix.length - 1; l++) smaller[k][l] = [];
}
```